# Is there any way to simplify this jQuery code or convert it into a loop or something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I am using multiple jquery cycle sliders on a single page that i am working on and using the same code for each of the sliders only the id is incrementing. i know there is a way to do this with a much simpler code. I have tried `.each()` but it doesn't work so any idea out there?

```
$('#rest-1 .rest-slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 750,
    slideExpr: 'img',
    next: '#rest-1 .slider-next',
    prev: '#rest-1 .slider-prev'
});

$('#rest-2 .rest-slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 750,
    slideExpr: 'img',
    next: '#rest-2 .slider-next',
    prev: '#rest-2.slider-prev'
});

$('#rest-3 .rest-slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 0,
    speed: 750,
    slideExpr: 'img',
    next: '#rest-3 .slider-next',
    prev: '#rest-3 .slider-prev'
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Untested, but this should work (assuming the ID's are the parent of the slider)

```
$('.rest-slider').each(function(){
    var id = '#' + $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(id + ' .rest-slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 750,
        slideExpr: 'img',
        next: id + ' .slider-next',
        prev: id + ' .slider-prev'
    });
});
```

Comment: That won't work. You don't know what the ID of the `.rest-slider`s are, and even if so, you're not in a calling context where `this` is the current element.

Comment: I realised that just after I'd posted it :) Edited it to have the parent

Comment: But the value of `this` is still unknown. Assuming the code is running in a `.ready()` callback, `this` will always be `document`.

Comment: Thanks for that RightSaidFred. I didn't realise that it didn't pass $(this) to the cycle. How about what I've amended it to?

Comment: The updated code works now but I've chosen nnnnnn's option 2 answer. thanks for the help. i'll keep this code handy.

Comment: That'll work as long as the element with the ID is a direct parent of the `.rest-slider` element. We can't really tell without seeing the HTML.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking RSF. Was really just trying to simplify the whole thing so that it required only the class for a selector and used the parent ID. I see you actually answered with something similar

Answer (score 0):

As with most problems of duplicate code, you can encapsulate the parts that don't change into a function.  In this case, the simplest solution would be a function that returns an object and takes the `next` and `prev` values as parameters.

```
function createCycleArg(nextVal, prevVal) {
    return {
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 750,
        slideExpr: 'img',
        next: nextVal,
        prev: prevVal
    };
}
```

And then...

```
$('#rest-1 .rest-slider').cycle(createCycleArg(
    '#rest-1 .slider-next', 
    '#rest-1 .slider-prev'));

$('#rest-2 .rest-slider').cycle(createCycleArg(
    '#rest-2 .slider-next', 
    '#rest-2 .slider-prev'));

$('#rest-3 .rest-slider').cycle(createCycleArg(
    '#rest-3 .slider-next', 
    '#rest-3 .slider-prev'));
```

You could break that down even further and just pass in a number since that's really the only thing that changes.

```
function createCycleArg(idNum) {
    return {
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 750,
        slideExpr: 'img',
        next: '#rest-' + idNum + ' .slider-next',
        prev: '#rest-' + idNum + ' .slider-prev'
    };
}
```

If there is some jquery specific way to do this better I wouldn't know it, but in general, throw the duplicated parts into a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each([1,2,3,4,5],function(i,v){
    $('#rest-'+v+' .rest-slider').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 750,
        slideExpr: 'img',
        next: '#rest-'+v+' .slider-next',
        prev: '#rest-'+v+' .slider-prev'
    });
})
```

Comment: You can't use the selector version of `each()` on an array, you need to use `$.each(...` instead

Comment: False, it can be used like that, just try it.

Comment: From the [docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/): "The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.". It might work but you shouldn't use it

Comment: Ivan: It may work right now but it is an unsupported use. For a general iterator, you should use `$.each()` like @Clive mentioned.

Comment: Don't forget also to replace `'#rest-3...` with `'#rest-' + v +...`

Comment: Okey, both things fixed now .

Answer (score 0):

Three ways come to mind: 1. Create a function that takes the ID as a parameter, 2. Define the IDs in an array and loop through the array, or 3. Use a loop to concatenate the loop counter into the ID string.

So, as I was typing I see another answer popped up with option 1 - see Ed S.'s answer.

Option 2, defining the list of IDs in advance (which will work nicely for IDs in any format, not just numbered ones):

```
var sliderIDs = ['#rest-1', '#rest-2', '#rest-3'];

$.each(sliderIDs, function(i,val) {
   $(val + ' .rest-slider').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      timeout: 0,
      speed: 750,
      slideExpr: 'img',
      next: val + ' .slider-next',
      prev: val + ' .slider-prev'
   }); 
});
```

Option 3, old-school loop counter concatenation:

```
for (var i=1; i <= 3; i++) {
   var id = '#rest-' + i;
   $(id + ' .rest-slider').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',
      timeout: 0,
      speed: 750,
      slideExpr: 'img',
      next: id + ' .slider-next',
      prev: id + ' .slider-prev'
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a general selector, along with `.each()`.

```
$('[id|="rest"] .rest-slider').each(function( i ) {
    $(this).cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 750,
        slideExpr: 'img',
        next: '#rest-' + (i+1) + ' .slider-next',
        prev: '#rest-' + (i+1) + ' .slider-prev'
    });
});
```

You should put the proper tag name before `[id|="rest"]`.